# Show JFrame when tray icon was clicked even if minimized

Tags: java, swing

I need to restore a hidden window when tray icon is clicked. I've actually already found partial solution:

```
tray_icon.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
    //Gui.this refers to my frame
    Gui.this.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

This will show the frame if it's behind another window. It will put the frame on top. But if I minimize the frame, it doesn't show the window. It's interesting however, that it slightly highlights the taskbar tab:

[image: image description]

Taskbar flashing is nice, but it's not enough:

- I want to **display the JFrame regardless of the way it was hidden**.

Note that I plan to allow "minimize to tray" function. This means I'll be even hiding the window completely (provided Java allows it). It still must be possible to show it.

Comment: Why the downvote again? I'm gettin' real tired of people downvoting my posts without any explanation.

Comment: 1. Why the downvote again? == because this is public forum, here are volunteers only, near, closest help desk is on freelancer.com, 2.  I'm gettin' real tired of people downvoting my posts without any explanation ==  because this is public forum, here is a few rulles that you pretty ignored, isn't it (everyone are too lazy notify you about, nor repeatly),  3. did you read an anwers to your questions, yes I'm bothering with == are simple, empty in most cases wrong, isn't it, near, closest help desk is on freelancer.com, 4. not your downvoter, but I'm fully agree with, we aren't hepldesk

Comment: @mKorbel Man could you write that again in english? I can only grasp that you propose that I ignored some rules. Which are these for start? Otherwise I totally lost you at: `Did you read an anwers to your questions, yes I'm bothering with == are simple, empty in most cases wrong, isn't it`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with `setVisible`, there's other thing to be set:

```
Gui.this.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
```

When minimized, the frame's state is Frame.ICONIFIED.

This is the complete callback to restore the hidden frame:

```
   tray_icon.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
       Gui.this.setVisible(true);
       Gui.this.setState (Frame.NORMAL);
     }
   }
```

And this is what I use to hide the window and taskbar panel (minimize to tray):

```
 this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
 {
    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent event) {
      //Hides it from screen
      Gui.this.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
      //Hides it from taskbar and screen
      Gui.this.setVisible(false);
    }
 });
```

Comment: @mKorbel What is that supposed to be?